# SQL - how to return exact matches only (special characters)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with words in spanish (INT id_word,VARCHAR(255) word). Lets suppose the table has these records:

- 1 casa
- 2 pantalon

If I search for the word **pantalón** (with a special char ó) it should **not** return any rows. How do I select exact matches only? It is currently returning the 2nd row.

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word='pantalón';
```

Thanks!

**Solution** from [ifx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201533/ifx), i changed the word field's collation to utf8_bin.

Comment: Useful reading about unicodes and collations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html What is your table encoding/collation?

Comment: Hi @biziclop - im using utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens is down to the collation. There are collations that are accent sensitive (which you want in this case) and other that are accent insensitive (which is what you currently have configured). There are also case-sensitive and case-insensitive collations.

**The following code produces the correct result:**

```
create table test (
    id int identity(1,1),
    value nvarchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AS
)

insert into test values ('casa')
insert into test values ('pantalon')

select value collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CS_AS from test where value = 'pantalón'
```

**The below code produces the incorrect result:**

```
drop table test
go

create table test (
    id int identity(1,1),
    value nvarchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI
)
insert into test values ('casa')
insert into test values ('pantalon')

select value collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CS_AS from test where value = 'pantalón'
```

The key here is the collation - **AI** means Accent-insensitive, **AS** means accent-sensitive.

Comment: i chose utf8_general_ci because the table actually holds words in spanish, chinese and portuguese. What would be the bes accent-sensitive collation to handle all language special chars? I changed it to utf8_bin and it worked fine.

Comment: utf8_bin is the most accurate, but you should be aware that the binary values of each character in a string is used for comparisons/sorting, so there is a potential performance impact during these operations.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem in our language too, so i did this, i have 2 coulmns for names, one of the i have named SearchColumn and the other one ViewColumn, when saving data I replace Special characters with other characters. when a user wants to search for something with the same function I do the changes and search it in the SearchColumn, if the search matches, I would display the value of the ViewColumn.

Comment: that would be too heavy for me, i have literally houndreds of thousands of rows. changing the collation works great!